# Know if Bluetooth is on, Flutter Blue

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am making an app based on Bluetooth functionality, in order to redirect the user to the correct page I need to know whether Bluetooth is on or not. Does anyone know how I can do that with Flutter Blue?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I actually solved the problem, it turned out I needed a BlueoothState in order to know whether it is active or not

Answer (score 2):

If you are using flutter blue, then this should work.

```
MaterialApp(
  color: Colors.white,
  home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
      stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
      initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final state = snapshot.data;
        if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
          return FindDevicesScreen();
        }
        return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
      }),
);
```

The state of Bluetooth is updated in the Stream of `FlutterBlue.instance.state`
You can easily access the state of Bluetooth using this stream.
FYI, for this to work you should ask for the permissions to use Bluetooth on any device.

Comment: Really appreciate it mate, I solved it a few minutes before your reply in exactly the same way. Really appreciate it